# How to Connect client to Azure SignalR for .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, azure, signalr

I expect an example on C# how to do it.
I can't find how to use Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR to connect to Azure SignalR from a desktop app.
I can do it with Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR, but it is only for .net >=4.6.1, when I need for .net 4.5.
The problem may be is how to pass connection string correctly (to get succeed hubConnection.Start).
So I need full procedure from HubConnection creation to it Start which can connect successfully.

---

Using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR is not a necessary condition. If other libraries, then please add also how to subscribe to the event.

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/09/17/the-future-of-asp-net-signalr/ Azure SignalR not yet supported

Comment: @GaneshR.14 days ago released the version with Azure SignalR support, but examples only for Asp.Net site.
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases